# MySQL - updating column with same value

Tags: mysql

MySQL states

> If you set a column to the value it currently has, MySQL notices this and does not update it.

So for example I have 20 columns and i am about to update them all but 10 of them will still have the same value. Will the performance or speed behaves the same way like you are updating just 10 columns? Or is it the other way around?

Comment: You could test this as quickly as asking, right?

Answer (score 0):

In your example, in the first case there will be 20 `checks` and 10 `updates`.

For 10 columns, there will be 10 `checks` and 10 `updates`.

So you "win" 10 `checks` in MySQL-side performance.